# How to use Freenode's webIRC client?

Tags: web, irc, freenode

I'm having trouble using Freenode's webIRC client:

[image]

I don't use IRC often, but I seem to recall we could actually chat with folks. But the webIRC seems to be missing an input box to type in.

I'm probably missing something really obvious.... How does one use Freenode's webIRC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input box is the white area at the bottom.

You could also try disabling all extensions/addons that you have, in case some of them are messing with webpages.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @noloader: From your screenshot it seems like you do; it's just all-white, without the border...

Comment: OK, thanks. Its probably something to do with EFF's HTTPSEverywhere. It breaks lots of sites. Usually I just dump the site. Can't do it this time, though....

Comment: Well, you _could_ dump the site this time too, and use a better IRC client like Textual or Linkinus or Hexchat or IRCCloud.

Comment: Thanks @grawity. It did not really matter. No one was in the advertised channel/room anyway (except others looking for the folks who told us to go there). I'd rather just dump IRC and use a mailing list. At least we can search a mailing list when no one is around.

Comment: @noloader I am pretty sure your input box is there - if you open the picture in a program like paint you can see there is infact  white bar across the bottom that matches grawity's. Did you try moving your cursor to the bottom 1/2 inch and around to see if your cursor changes to the text cursor?